# How to connect to 2 different cosmos Databases in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect to 2 cosmos databases in Java springboot application. If I define
azure.cosmos.database ="somevalue"

It always picks the above value though in AppConfig I am using a different databases to create a bean.

if I remove the azure.cosmos.database from application.yml, It give the following error:
Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'azure.cosmos' to com.azure.spring.autoconfigure.cosmos.CosmosProperties failed:

```
Property: azure.cosmos.uri
Value: null
Reason: must not be empty

Property: azure.cosmos.database
Value: null
Reason: must not be empty

Property: azure.cosmos.key
Value: null
Reason: must not be empty
```

Any suggestion or inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the code what you tried?